# Java thread safety in singleton scoped class methods

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

So I have a Singleton class and in it a non-static public method that is called by multiple threads. In the non-static method I have local references to objects created by a Stored Procedure which I surmise means the 'new' keyword gets called somewhere.

```
 1 public void someMethod(SomeObjectParameter parameter) {
 2      
 3     Thing thingOne = synchornizedStoredProcedureCall(): 
 4     doSomethingWith(thingOne);
 5     doSomethingElseWith(thingOne);
 6
 7 }
```

Currently lines 3 through 5 are in a synchronized code block which I would like to reduce down to just having the stored procedure call as synchronized.

So... Say we have two threads, Thread1 and Thread2. Thread1 is about to execute line 3 and Thread2 is about to execute line 4. Since this is a local reference, will each thread maintain a different reference or will synchornizedStoredProcedureCall overwrite the reference to thingOne as doSomethingWith is about to use it?

What if thingOne is declared final or if I made it immutable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> will each thread maintain a different reference or will synchornizedStoredProcedureCall overwrite the reference to thingOne as doSomethingWith is about to use it?

The different threads have different stacks.  The `thingOne` is stored in the per-thread stack so cannot be overwritten by the other thread.  You also need to make sure that the `synchornizedStoredProcedureCall()` is returning a different instance of `Thing` each time and not a `static` or instance variable.  Both threads need to be working on different `Thing` instances.

As long as the `doSomethingWith(...)` and `doSomethingElseWith(...)` calls are thread safe and only work with `thingOne` argument and constants (etc), protecting *just* the `synchornizedStoredProcedureCall()` should be fine.

As @Marko points out, without seeing the `Thing` class, we cannot be guaranteed that it is thread-safe and not storing internal state.

Comment: I believe the MyBatis DAO does create a new object on each call. I've not seen any counter-indications in previous thread testing. Thing is actually just a model object that has no static fields and only getters/setters.

Comment: So if local variables and local object references created with 'new' are per thread as this response indicates, that would seem to be the answer. There is a later occasion where we are pulling a date out of it but in the getter we make a copy to avoid giving out the internal reference.

OK, I've also verified that the 'new' keyword is used to generate Thing so these should all be different.

Comment: In response to the 1st sentence.  Yes.  I don't have enough context to comment on the 2nd half.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on a lot of details that you haven't presented. Many details about the `Thing` class matter: it could have some internally shared state that may not be thread-safe (see the *Flyweight* design pattern). These facts must be documented in the class Javadoc; otherwise it would be very difficult to find it out from source code.

Answer (score 0):

Thingone is thread safe anyway as it is declared threadlocal on the stack. If thingone was an instance variable not declared within a method, you would have problems; but it isn;t - so you don't.

Answer (score 0):

your thingOne is local variable. it is thread safe. Each thread gets its own copy of locals.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure that `thingOne` is not shared.  Even though it is returned from a synchronized method, if it is a member of the singleton returned from `synchornizedStoredProcedureCall` , your implementation is no longer thread safe.

Comment: synchornizedStoredProcedureCall does not return a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

Each thread will maintain a different reference. That would be even the case if someMethod was static.

You still have to be sure that the Thing instances are thread safe themslef. E.g. the Thing class doesn't have static fields nor the two Thing instance have a non-static field pointing to the same object, or if they do they handle them in a thread safe way.